# Excel Export Junk characters in Play Framework 1.2.5.3

Tags: excel, playframework, export-to-excel

I am using Play framework 1.2.5.3 with excel module:
https://www.playframework.com/modules/excel

```
    public static void createXLSUsers2() {
          Logger.info("generateNameCard");
          List<User> users = User.findAll();
          request.format = "xls";
          renderArgs.put("__EXCEL_FILE_NAME__", "downloadUsers.xls");
          render(users);
    }
```

using above code.

However, I am getting the junk chars in output. I have tried apache POI library and jexcel library without any success every library is showing the same chunk characters on downloaded file.

Something is wrong when play when it is sending the file as response, as tried creating the file on local system it was without any junk characters.

downloaded file looks like this:

[image: excel image]

Comment: got it was using gizzip which was the culprit :(

Comment: solved few other issues also here http://subodh-gupta.blogspot.com/2015/01/play-framework-12x-excel-export-with.html